# Error "Cannot use mean strategy with non-numeric data" in making column transformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm doing Housing Price Prediction competition on Kaggle. When I'm dealing with data, there're missing values and categorical data. So I do preprocessing to everything but it doesn't work well.
Let me show my code:

```
x_train = train_data.drop("SalePrice", axis=1)
```

I do droping entire columns is more than 1100. The dataset shape is [1460 rows x 80 columns]

```
drop_col = null[null>1100].index.tolist()
drop_col = drop_col + ['Id']
```

I try to impute columns less than 1100 null values.

```
impute_col = [column for column, count in null.items() if 1 <= count <= 1100]
```

I collect categorical columns to do OneHotEncoding

```
cat_columns = x_train.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
```

I start to create ColumnTransformer

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)
impute = IterativeImputer()
ct = make_column_transformer(
    (impute, impute_col),
    (ohe, cat_columns),
    ('drop', drop_col),
    remainder ='passthrough'
)
ct.fit_transform(x_train)
```

But that's the point I got error, it shows like this:

```
ValueError: Cannot use mean strategy with non-numeric data:
could not convert string to float: 'TA'
```

I tried some ways but still can't. So what should I fix this problem?
If you want to get train file, check this out https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data?select=train.csv

I've done one similar project like this, but now although I use same steps, I couldn't solve